# Test of a normed vector space to be a direct sum with closed summand

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed vector space, $X_1$ subspace of $X$. There exists such closed subspace $X_2$ of $X$ that $X = X_1 \oplus X_2$ if one of the following conditions stands:

1. $\dim X_1 < \infty$;
2. $X_1$ is closed and $\dim X/X_1 < \infty$;
3. $X/X_1 \cong l_1$ as normed vector spaces.

How do I prove these implications?

Comment: @TZakrevskiy, $X_2=X$ is closed in $X$, isn't it?

Comment: @TZakrevskiy, oh, sorry, now I've read your comment more carefully. You implied that $X$ is not closed. You see, in this context $X$ is the largest space, and all of its subspaces are considered to be closed/not closed *in $X$*. Hence the whole $X$ is closed.

Comment: Hm, it seems I confused closed and complete spaces, sorry.